# How to choose a java plugin version for Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, plugins, applet

I need your help, please.
I have to start an applet in Internet Explorer, but using an old version of jre.

My IE has two versions of java plugin, and I would like to enable the old jre version, but only for the web site using the applet.
So, my question is : how can I change plugin version when internet explorer start? Is it possible?
I need to have one specific shortcut (for IE), which launch the web site, with the strange applet. And so the standard IE in all others cases.

I hope my english is good enough, for a good understanding....

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: *"I have to start an applet in Internet Explorer, but using an old version of jre."* Oracle seems to have dropped support for loading older versions of the JRE.  I guess they got sick of chasing security bugs in them.  As such, your best chance is to ensure the applet can work with the latest JREs.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew. There are somme issues with code, because of stranges happenings. But I don't have access to the source code.... To make changes...